# Notification not showing Android 7.0 but showing in Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I have a service which displays a notification, the notification works in Android 6.0 and prior but it doesnt show up in 7.0.

Relevant code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntentMain = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent_main, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Notification notificationPopup = new Notification.Builder(this).setContentTitle("Alarm is ON!").setContentText("Click here")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntentMain).setAutoCancel(true).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.acd).setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL).build();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationPopup);
```

Comment: can you post ur manfest.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow up this steps and let me know it works or not
Remove 6ya from Battery Optimization:

1.Go to setting battery.

2.Click the Menu on battery page and choose battery optimization.

3.Clicked on Not optimized and go to all apps.

4.On All Apps locate 6ya app and click on it.

5.It will show a pop-up with Optimize and Don't optimize.

6.Click on Don't optimize and hit DONE.

7.6ya Should be located on the not optimized folder .

8.All set - restart the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I have not been able to reproduce the problem you're seeing.

In my tests, this code creates and displays the notification successfully on Android 5.1, 6.0, 7.0 and 7.1.1:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));

    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // create and display a notification
        Intent intent_main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentMain = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent_main, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Notification notificationPopup = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Alarm is ON!")
                .setContentText("Click here")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntentMain)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationPopup);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```